FB of new filtering feature of ros2 doctor tool
I posted a couple of weeks ago in the ros2cli repository an issue regarding the creation of a new flag in order to exclude package information from the reports published by this tool.
The reason why I came up with this? I was following ROS 2 Jazzy tutorials and noticed that the Package Version prompt was inmensive in comparison with the other information provided, and I thought that most of the times, you would not want to check the package versions each time you run ros2 doctor.
I attach a link to the feature itself, where you can see the feedback given by fujitatomiya and me, but I would like to have more opinions to see if this feature might be interesting and if the solution given would be fitting to the standards. Link here
Nothing more and hope you a great coding!
